# Get coordinate(x,y) from xml file and put it into float list

Tags: python, xml, list

I want to put several coordinates (x, y) recovered from an xml file in a list  that I can used  with a drawcontour or polyline function
the problem is that I don't know how to put them in a list I used liste.append but its not working :( please help me

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TwoDimensionSpatialCoordinate>
    <coordinateIndex value="0"/>
        <x value="302.6215607602997"/>
        <y value="166.6285651861381"/>
    <coordinateIndex value="1"/>
        <x value="3.6215607602997"/>
        <y value="1.6285651861381"/>
</TwoDimensionSpatialCoordinate>
```

```
import xml.dom.minidom


def main(file):
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
    values = doc.getElementsByTagName("coordinateIndex")
    coordX = doc.getElementsByTagName("x")
    coordY = doc.getElementsByTagName("y")
    d = []
    for  atr_x in  coordX:
        for   atr_y in  coordY:
            x = atr_x.getAttribute('value')
            y = atr_y.getAttribute('value')
            print("x",x,"y",y)
    d.append(x)
    d.append(y)
    print(d)


result = main('1.631791322.58809740.14.834982.40440.3641459051.955.6373933.1920.xml')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
x 302.6215607602997 y 179.53418754193044
x 317.14038591056607 y 179.53418754193044
x 328.11016491298955 y 179.53418754193044
x 337.6280614003864 y 179.53418754193044
x 350.0497229178365 y 179.53418754193044
x 363.9232669503133 y 179.53418754193044
```

This result is when I get the x,y coordination from xml file but when I add `d.append` it doesn't define the `d`:
`NameError: name 'd' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your XML is strange (`x` and `y` are not in `coordinateIndex`)
2. Indentation matters in python
3. You probably want to try ElementTree, which is considered a better alternative to minidom
4. Working code for minidom and your input format

```
def main(file):
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
    coordX = doc.getElementsByTagName("x")
    coordY = doc.getElementsByTagName("y")
    d = []
    for atr_x, atr_y in zip(coordX, coordY):
        x = atr_x.getAttribute('value')
        y = atr_y.getAttribute('value')
        print("x", x, "y", y)
        d.append(x)
        d.append(y)
    return d
```

Comment: thank you for your help my problem is i need to extract from the liste the  x,y coordination to use it in drawcontour function so i need every couple of (x,y)

Comment: You said you need a list of floats, If you need tuples (x, y) just add them instead of adding x and y separately

Comment: if you mean to add the tuple(x,y) with append it doesn't work for me

Comment: You need to be more specific. What output do you expect and what you receive

Comment: i need to draw contour with the list of cordinate(x,y) that i parse it from xml file

Answer (score 0):

it's work now :D i put the code in case someone need it later

```
import xml.dom.minidom
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def main(file):
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
    coordX = doc.getElementsByTagName("x")
    coordY = doc.getElementsByTagName("y")
    d = []
    for atr_x, atr_y in zip(coordX, coordY):
        x = atr_x.getAttribute('value')
        y = atr_y.getAttribute('value')
        #print("x", x, "y", y)
        d.append(x)
        d.append(y)

    a = map(float, d)
    print(tuple(zip(a, a)))

    return a  

result = main('1.631791322.58809740.14.834982.40440.3641459051.955.6373933.1920.xml')
print(result)
```